# Circular dependency in angular 4

Tags: angular, service, module, warnings, circular-dependency

I'm getting the following warning whenever I run my project:

> Circular dependency detected: src/app/Dashboard/dashboard.module.ts ->
>   src/app/Dashboard/finance.service.ts ->
>   src/app/Dashboard/dashboard.module.ts

In my finances.service I have a function that creates an object of type "Statistics" which is a class that I defined on my dashboard.module

**dashboard.module**

```
export class Stadistics {
  mod: number;
  min: number;
  max: number;
}
```

**finance.service**

```
 getStatistics(array: Array<number>) {
    const stats = new Statistics;
    stats.max = 0;
    stats.min = 0;
    stats.mod = 0;
}
```

I also tried using: const stats: Statistics = new Statistics; but I keep getting the same warning. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you forgotten () after new Statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard approach in such a case is to move declarations causing circular dependencies into separate source file. So, it could look something like this:

**statistics.class.ts**

```
export class Statistics {
    mod: number;
    min: number;
    max: number;
}
```

**finance.service.ts**

```
import {Statistics} from './statistics.class';
....
....
....
getStatistics(array: Array<number>) {
    const stats = new Statistics();
    stats.max = 0;
    stats.min = 0;
    stats.mod = 0;
}
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
import {Statistics} from './statistics.class';

// use it here where you need it.
```

Of course, you need to think through very carefully how to split your sources so that it would make sense.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. Any idea why does this happens? I have a lot of classes in dashboard.module and only Statistics gave this warning.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many classes or which classes or other entities are causing it. Circular dependency is on the **file** level. Maybe this class was picked as first by compiler using some criteria, or maybe this dependency appeared when you first introduced this class... who knows :)